# What happened to the official documentation of web3.js v1.0?

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

It should be at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/, but now I'm getting this:

[image]

Does anybody happen to know why this wonderful tool has been taken off line?

Comment: If they can't upgrade a webpage without breaking it, how will they ever roll out casper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a newer version out mate.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/

Comment: Yes, but where can we find the old documentation ... ?

Answer (score 2):

They came up with a official new release document on 6th of August for **v1.***, find that [here](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/web3js/v1.2.1/web3js.pdf).

[Here](https://medium.com/@samuel_91690/1-0-release-web3-js-ddd23d3c8f62) is the official announcement medium channel.